# How to limit parent div width to the least child's width?

Tags: html, css

Can I do this without Javascript?

Here is the mock markup..

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="child1"> ... </div>
 <div id="child2"> ... </div>
</div>
```

I want the parent div to have a width of the least of its child div.

I my particular scenario I have a variable width image inside one of the div
I want the rest of divs to limit themselves to the width of the img div.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without javascript. Is there a reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: if you know the size of the images cant you set to the least one?? and if you want it to be dynamic well you are in a problem with Javascript no go attitude..

Comment: I am trying to design it to be fluid and the image has a fixed percent height which will change based on browser width, I think it wont be a smooth transition if i use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comment: well you can always not show your main div until JS is done executing.
your markup will look as follows:

```
<div id="parent" style="diplay:none">
 <div class="child" style="width:100px"> ... </div>
 <div class="child" style="width:50px"> ... </div>
</div>​
```

Js Code:

```
var childELements=document.getElementsByClassName("child");
var minWidth=999999;
for(var i=0;i<childELements.length;i++)
{
var width=childELements[i].getWidth();
    if(width<minWidth)
    {
      minWidth=width;                    
    }
}

var parent=document.getElementById("parent");
parent.style.width=String(minWidth)+"px";
parent.style.display="block";
```

**[Live ​Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7G7hH/4/)**

​

Comment: note, i am not sure if all the functions above are supported by all the browsers.. dnt curse me for that.. I did not give you a jquery soln (you should be thankful for that) :D

Comment: Thankyou, looks like it is not possible to do without javascript,I will be implementing as your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.min(parseInt(document.getElementById("child1")), parseInt(document.getElementById("child2")));
```

No CSS solution to this possible.